# Configure Nginx to be a TCP load balancer

Tags: nginx, tcp, load-balancing

I want to use Nginx 1.9 to be a TCP load balancer. I followed the tutorial in https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/tcp-load-balancing/ but it didn't work.

Every time I tried to start nginx, I've got errors:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "stream" in /opt/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
# blah blah blah
}

stream {
    upstream backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:9630;
        server 127.0.0.1:9631;
    }
    server {
        listen 2802;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        proxy_timeout 3s;
        proxy_pass backend;
    }
}
```

Would you pls tell me how to configure it right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way is compiling nginx from source to support `stream` directive:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx  --conf-path=/opt/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --with-http_ssl_module --with-threads --with-stream --with-http_slice_module
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 6):

Using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) on OS X, this can be done with:

```
brew install nginx-full --with-stream
```

This might ask you to first install the `homebrew-nginx` tap, in which case you might have to run

```
brew install homebrew/nginx/nginx-full --with-stream
```

to make sure that the tap gets installed first.

Comment: You might want the stream SSL module as well. I was trying to get a functionally equivalent build to the one used in the Alpine nginx docker image, and they're using the same build parameters as the pre-built official nginx binaries:

Comment: `--with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-threads --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-http_slice_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-http_v2_module --with-ipv6`

Comment: Install with brew and SSL stream, but with no luck: `brew install homebrew/nginx/nginx-full --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module`. It seems to just strip the latter (along with any unknown parameters). I can verify this with `nginx -V`. In fact, of the list @DanielSmedegaardBuus posted, only `--with-mail` and `--with-stream` seem to work. I solved it by installing it on my linux VM instead, but maybe someone here knows the solution using brew?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using linux, there are [nginx standard repositories](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
./configure --with-stream
make
make install
```